# Find the limits for two triangle functions by using fundamental limit.

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I occurred two problems about finding limit today. The questions ask finding limit by using the fundamental limit.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x }{x } = 1$$

The questions will show below as a picture. (Sorry I am really not familiar with math format)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFGf3.jpg)

Here are the limits.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \tan(x^2)}{\cos(5x)\sin^3(3x)}
$$

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{(2x-\pi)\tan(2x)}
$$

Comment: I entered the equations. Take a look so you can do it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start on what you need:

$\tan(x)
=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos(x)
=1
$

$\sin(\pi/2-x)
=\cos(x)
$

$\cos(\pi/2-x)
=\sin(x)
$